# Date coming as undefined with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

```
       function duplicateWithLines()
        {
          var datefield = jQuery("#lineItemDate").val();
          if ( !( datefield && datefield.match( /^\d{1,2}[/]\d{1,2}[/]\d{4}$/ ) ) ) alert("Date is required");
          else {
           //DO blah blah
          }
        }
    ---
    ---

          <input type='button' class='duplicate_button' name='duplicateWithLines' value='Duplicate Line Items:' onClick='duplicateWithLines()'/>
          <hsi:calendar name="lineItemDate" size='10' maxlength='10' />
```

At Line  var datefield = jQuery("#lineItemDate").val(); value is coming as undefined I think.    Because of that it failing to enter else block.if condition is satisfying so alert msg printed. But it has to enter else block.
And there date format would be entered as dd/mm/yyyy.
What is the way to get in to else block.

Comment: What's `<hsi:calendar`?  What is the *actual* HTML on your page (view source)?

Answer (score 1):

Addressing the `val()`-problem: you are trying to find an element with **id** `lineItemDate`. But your element has no id. It does have a **name**, so `$('[name=lineItemDate]').val()` should work.

If the formatting is fixed (`dd/mm/yyyy`), try modifiyng the `if` part this way to avoid the ugly and expensive matching:

```
var dateFromValue = new Date(
                     $('[name=lineItemDate]').val().split('/').reverse().join('-')
                    );
if (!isnNaN(dateFromValue)) {
   /* it's a date! */
} else {
  /* don't bother */
}
```

While we're at it, don't use inline handlers. Every activation of an inline handler spawns a new javascript interpreter. In your scripting use:

```
$('[name=duplicateWithLines]').on('click', duplicateWithLines);
```

It may be wise to rename your function, to avoid name clashes.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't know how to retrieve the value from the `hsi:calendar` element. You need to find the html element that contains the data value in order to use jquery to fetch it.

Comment: With hsi:calendar it able to get date asdd/mm/yyyy format, and it populated that date in the textfield. but at line                 var datefield = jQuery("#lineItemDate").val();                            it is failing I guess

Comment: yes, but the idea of the textfield (which I assume is an element `<input type='text'>`) has it's own id, which is what you should pass into jQuery.  this `hsi:calendar` is non-standard, so jquery can't deal with it.

Comment: can you suggest solution with above case.You mean to say we can only pass that html element id to jquery?